# Flash 5.5 video player error: undefined property PLAYHEAD_UPDATE

Tags: flash, air, flash-cs5

I'm getting this error:

> Access of possibly undefined property PLAYHEAD_UPDATE through a
>   reference with static type Class

in an AIR app of mine, ever since upgrading to 5.5 (from 5).

There's an adobe [forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/860033) that addresses this but no solution is offered (as per usual).

Has anyone else encountered this and were you able to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I guess no one is going to chime in with thoughts, so, I'll just point to the forum thread that suggests an alternative (it doesn't actually say how to fix the bug, or that this is even deemed a bug), but I'm not sure that any better idea is going to come along.